# How to find an injective affine map mapping a square in $R^2$ to the triangle in $R^3$ with vertices $(0,0,0), (1,1,1), (1,1,2)$?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

How to find an injective affine map mapping some square(sets of the form $[a,b] \times [c,d]$) in $R^2$ to the triangle in $R^3$ with vertices $(0,0,0), (1,1,1), (1,1,2)$?

Comment: There is none. No affine injective map may send three non-collinear points into three collinear points. In general, the image of a convex $n$-agon through an affine injective map is still a convex $n$-agon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such map.

An affine map will map lines to lines and preserve incidences between points and lines. An injective map has at most one preimage for every image. If your original square had corners $A,B,C,D$ and your triangle has corners $P,Q,R$, you could assume one of two cases: either all square corners get mapped to triangle corners. Then one triangle corner would have two preimages, in violation to the injective property. Or one square corner would get mapped to some point along the edge of the triangle. W.l.o.g. we may assume $A\mapsto P,B\mapsto Q,C\mapsto R,D\mapsto X$ with $X$ a point on the segment $PR$. The diagonal $AC$ in the original square must map to the line $PR$ as lines are preserved. But $D$ does not lie on $AC$, so if it still maps to $PR$ as well, that would mean some point on $PR$ would have two preimages. Again in violation of the injective property.